# Construction of Quot schemes and construction of certain closed subschemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I am still studying Nitsure's [Construction of Hilbert and Quot schemes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504590.pdf), and I am yet again stuck, this time on page 25. I understand what lemma 5.4 says, but I do not get its proof. Let me sketch the outline:

$X\longrightarrow S$ is a projective morphism where $S$ is Noetherian, and $\psi:E\longrightarrow F$ a surjective morphism between coherent $X$-sheaves. They construct a closed subscheme $T'\subseteq T$ as follows:

> [...] This is satisfied by taking $T'$ to be the vanishing scheme for the composite homomorphism $\ker(\phi)\hookrightarrow E\longrightarrow F$ of coherent sheaves over $X_{T}$.

To me, the $T'$ thus constructed is a subset of $X_{T}$, not of $T$.

**EDIT**: Also, why exactly does this lemma prove that the representability of $\mathfrak{Quot}^{\phi,L}_{G/X/S}$ implies the representability of $\mathfrak{Quot}^{\phi,L}_{E/X/S}$?

Comment: This is explained in Remark 3.6, as linked in the proof. A morphism of sheaves on $X_T$ that is flat over $T$ gives rise to a map from $T$ to the moduli space $\bf V$ described in Theorem 3.5. Those points of $T$ which parametrize the zero homomorphism are mapped to the zero section of $\bf V$, which you are then pulling back to $T$ to obtain $T'$.

Comment: I see. There is a typo in Remark 3.6. It should read "... then the inverse image $\varphi^{−1}_{f}\mathbf{V}_{0}...$ But I still don't get why this $T'$ has the desired properties.

Comment: The key point seems to be that the pullback $E_U \to \mathcal F_U$ factors through $G_U$ precisely if $\ker(\phi)|_U \hookrightarrow E_U \to \mathcal F_U$ is the zero map. So $T'$ is the locus in $T$ cut out by a certain (canonical?) section of $\mathcal Hom (\ker(\phi), \mathcal F)$.